# Javascript User input Average GPA calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a user input gpa calculator with the help of javascript. Logic is that, User can only enter A,B,C,D,F value. Then it will calculate the average result with pop up. If result 3.50 or above then pop up average result with congratulation else sorry with average result.

I was trying to solve it from 2 days. But no luck. Can you give me any hints to solve this?
If I enter value, it shows NaN, but if I keep empty, then it shows 0.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jL8p1g80/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>GPA Calculation </title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <!-- Calculator html design start from here --> 


        <hr>
        <br>
        <h2>GPA Calculation</h2>
        <h3>Here use GPA Scale: A = 4; B = 3; C = 2; D = 1; F = 0</h3>

        <br>
    <CENTER>

    <!-- This is html form -->  
    <FORM Name="GPACalcForm">
    <TABLE BORDER=5 BGCOLOR=#C0C0C0 CELLPADDING="5" 
    CELLSPACING="2">
    <TH></TH>
    <TH>Grade</TH>

    <TR>
    <TD>Class 1</TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=5 NAME="GR1" ALIGN=TOP 
    MAXLENGTH=5></TD>

    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD>Class 2</TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=5 NAME="GR2" ALIGN=TOP 
    MAXLENGTH=5></TD>

    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD>Class 3</TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=5 NAME="GR3" ALIGN=TOP 
    MAXLENGTH=5></TD>

    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD>Class 4</TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=5 NAME="GR4" ALIGN=TOP 
    MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
    </TR>



    <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
    <TD COLSPAN=3><INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Calculate" 
    NAME="CalcButton"
    OnClick="gpacalc()"></TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </FORM>
    <BR>
    <P>

    <P>
    </CENTER>

    <BR>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function gpacalc()
{
//define valid grades and their values
var gr = new Array(5); 
var cr = new Array(5);
var ingr = new Array(3);


// define valid grades and their values


var grcount = 5; 
gr[0] = "A";
cr[0] = 4;
gr[1] = "B";
cr[1] = 3;
gr[2] = "C";
cr[2] = 2;
gr[3] = "D";
cr[3] = 1;
gr[4] = "F";
cr[4] = 0;



// retrieve user input
ingr[0] = document.GPACalcForm.GR1.value;
ingr[1] = document.GPACalcForm.GR2.value;
ingr[2] = document.GPACalcForm.GR3.value;
ingr[3] = document.GPACalcForm.GR4.value;

// Calculate GPA
var allgr =0;
var gpa = 0;


for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
        if (ingr[x] == "") break;  // if empty value then stop
        var validgrcheck = 0;
        for (var xx = 0; xx < grcount; xx++)
                {
                if (ingr[x] == gr[xx])
                        {
                        allgr = allgr + (parseInt(ingr[x],10)); 

                        validgrcheck = 1;
                        break;
                        }
                }
        if (validgrcheck == 0)
                {
                alert("Error- Please use standard college grades in the form of A B C D F.");
                return 0;
                }
        }

gpa = allgr;

if(eval(gpa) >=3.50) {

alert("CONGRATULATION! your GPA =  " + eval(gpa)); 

return 0;
    }
    else {
        alert("Thanks for try your GPA =  " + eval(gpa));
        return 0;
    }
}


</SCRIPT>


</div>

    <div class="footer">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't capitalize html elements and attributes, and place your attribute values in quotes. You should replace: `<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=5 NAME="GR4" ALIGN=TOP 
MAXLENGTH=5></TD>` with `<td><input type="text" size="5" name="GR4" align="top" 
maxlength="5"></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line `(parseInt(ingr[x],10))`. Here you are trying to parse a character ('A','B',etc) as an integer and the result is `NaN`. Instead try

`allgr = allgr + (cr[x],10);`

to calculate the GPA.

BTW, I don't see the logic to calculate the average.

Comment: OP should use `cr[xx]` instead of `cr[x]` and calculate the GPA with `gpa=allgr/4;`

Comment: Thanks it's working. I am getting total result now. Can you give another hints for making average.

Comment: Since you have four inputs, I'd suggest dividing the result by 4. @Niddro's comment might help you.

Comment: @Arunster  No i cannot do that. Because if user input only 1 or two field  then it will produce wrong result.

Comment: @Niddro But if their user input only one or two field then? I think dividing by 4 will not work.

Comment: @Mehedi Depends on how you want your code to work, right now it seems as if you're stopping your script if one field isn't filled in: `if (ingr[x] == "") break;` so an average would only be calculated if all fields are filled. What you could do, if you want the user to be able to only fill in a few fields is to introduce a new variable that counts how many fields had data in them. So, where you add points to allgr, you can also do `counter++;`